Which parameters should I modify in order to get a loopclouse using SLAM toolbox
I am testing the slam toolbox to generate a map, but with the default parameters using SYNC mode, I'm getting a bad loop closure map. Maybe because of the lack of information in this area (it is an semi outdoors environment) 
Can you recommend any parameters to modify in the slam configuration? i have tried with minimum_travel_distance and heading.

Id take a look at this block (but also others) https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/blob/ros2/config/mapper_params_online_async.yaml#L60-L63
As the name suggests, this is the size of the area the loop closure search is attempted at. Its currently set as 8m, which is plenty for most situations. However if you have a really long corridor without intermediate areas to correct drift, that drift is just going to accumulate.
As such, the longer you go without a loop closure & you have a platform without good odometry, you need to increase the window you search for loop closures within to widen the potential candidates. It will make the SLAM problem proportionately slower since its doing more work, but that's the nature of what you're asking it to do.

Thanks, I'll try!
Also, an additional doubt: In the meantime tried editing the posegraph with interactive markers, but the changes seemed to be restrictive compared with the markers displacement, (video attached below). I imagine this is desirable since I am moving a pair of nodes, but there is a good reason to think that this approach is going to work... for example, to fix the previous mapping session? the same parameters or other parameters are applied when using interactive markers?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BPI9OqWIzlOFw_xvGBM0AmyhdG2ZZyTs/view?usp=sharing

Its going to reoptimize for potential changes in constraints to correct for problems, but it doesn't trigger new loop closure attempts. Perhaps that could be added, but that's a non-trivial software modification.

I think is most about the overlap area or the data quality,
I followed the steps increasing tf_buffer_duration, stack_size_to_use, correlation_search_space_dimension and loop_search_space_dimension but the results seems equal.
